# Нет вкладок packages и behaviors в отчете allure при запуске из jenkins

Tags: jenkins, allure

Установил allure-commandline автоматически из Maven central(v. 2.10.0). Настроил генерацию отчета в сборке, запустил. Отчет генерируется успешно, но вкладки packages и behaviors в панели слева отсутствуют. Если генерировать отчет из версии 2.9.0 установленной на машине на том же allure-report, то вкладки есть. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается в Allure Jenkins plugin версии 2.28.0 ввели обязательную проверку config.yml лежащую в рабочей папке проекта. В моем случае его там не было, соответственно behaviors &packages плагины не были подключены. Проблема на момент ответа решена закидыванием файла конфига со следующим текстом в рабочую папку и указанием пути к нему в сборке (расширенные настройки Allure Report):

```
plugins:
  - behaviors-plugin
  - packages-plugin
```